# Review on efficiency and correctness appreciated for my first single-page website

Tags: optimization, html, css

I've taught myself some basic HTML/CSS over the past few weeks and just finished up my first horizontally scrolling single page site last night. I went for a clean minimal design and achieved the look I was going for, but am absolutely sure I did some things the hard way. Would really appreciate any advice on how I could have made the code cleaner and more efficient. Criticism welcome.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>stan's page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "fonts.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "header.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li id="home_link"><a href="#home">home</a></li><li id="about_link"><a href="#aboutme">about</a></li><li id="work_link"><a href="#work">work</a></li><li id="contact_link"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="home">
            <div id="homeinfo">
                <p>hi there</p><br><p>my name's stan</p><br><p>i'm an aspiring developer</p><br><p>it's quite the pleasure to meet you</p>
            </div>
            <div id="homepic">
                <img src ="homepic.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="aboutme">
            <h1>about me</h1>
            <div id="leftlist">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                    <li>consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                    <li>sed do eiusmod tempor</li>
                    <li>incididunt ut labore et dolore</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="rightlist">
                <ul>
                    <li>magna aliqua</li>
                    <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam</li>
                    <li>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</li>
                    <li>nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="work">
            <h1>my work thus far</h1>
            <img src="lipsum.jpg">
            <img src="janblom.jpg">
            <img src="reddit.jpg">
            <h1>more to come...</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="contact">
            <h1>contact</h1>
            <img src="email.png">
            <img src="facebook.png">
            <img src="twitter.png">
            <img src="linkedin.png">
            <img src="googleplus.png">
            <img src="github.png">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header{
    z-index:1;
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#8a6954;
    position:fixed;
    float:top;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

#header ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header li{
    width:25%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:surrounding;
    font-weight:900;
    margin-top:5px;
}

#header a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#header a:link{
    color:#89B57F;
}

#header a:visited{
    color:#7A8FA9;
}

#header a:hover{
    color:#465F40;
}

#header a:active{
    color:#1D2E45;
}

#home{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#355851;
    height:700px;
    clear:top;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#homeinfo{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    padding-right:50px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    margin-left:-450px;
}

#homeinfo p{
    font-family:surrounding;
    color:#82A7A0;
    font-size:30px;
    padding:0;
}

#homepic{
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-182px;
    margin-left:auto;
    padding-left:40px;
}

#homepic img{
    height:370px;
    width:385px;
}

#aboutme{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#7A8FA9;
    height:700px;
    margin-top:700px;
    font-family:surrounding;
}

#aboutme h1{
    color:#1D2E45;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:150px;
    font-size:72px;
    color:#1D2E45;
}

#leftlist, #rightlist{
    font-size:30px;
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    color:#1D2E45;
}

#leftlist li{
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

#leftlist{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    padding-right:50px;
    margin-top:-70px;
    margin-left:-450px;
}

#rightlist{
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-314px;
}

#work{
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height:700px;
    margin-top:1400px;
    background-color:#4E7346;
    font-family:surrounding;
}

#work h1{
    color:#94B58D;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:80px;
    font-size:72px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

#work img{
    height:250px;
    width:400px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-bottom:-40px;
}

#contact{
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:700px;
    margin-top:2100px;
    background-color:#314944;
    font-family:surrounding;
}

#contact h1{
    color:#8A6954;
    margin-top:250px;
    font-size:72px;
}
```

There's a separate fonts.css file which just imports the fonts from my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The br element is being misused here.  If you wish to have your paragraphs spaced farther apart, adjust their margins via CSS.

The text "more to come..." appears within an h1 tag, but what is it a headline for?  Use the semantically appropriate tag for the content in question, don't choose a tag because of how it looks.  Any tag could be styled via CSS to look like an h1.

There is no `top` value for the `float` or `clear` properties (`#header`) and paddings can't have negative values (`#work img`).  Validating your CSS would have caught this.

Setting fixed dimensions on elements containing text (`#header`) is a good way to set yourself up for failure.  Text is fluid by nature.  Even though you feel you have provided the appropriate amount of space, there are many variables that are out of your hands:

- The user may not have the font you've specified and is using a fallback font that has slightly different font attributes (maybe you've seen a comparison between Helvetica for Mac vs Windows?)
- The user might have have adjusted their desired font-size for accessibility reasons
- The user might have set a minimum font-size that is larger than your desired font-size

Using relative font-sizes would minimize this problem (but not completely eliminate it):

```
element {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1;
    height: 2em;
}
```

When you float an element, most display types are ignored so there's no reason to specify them (`#header li`).  Floated elements secretly get their display type modified to something that's *like* but not quite inline-block.

What's the deal with all of the absolutely positioned elements (`#home`, `#aboutme`, etc.)?  Generally speaking, absolute positioning for layout purposes should be avoided.  Just like I mentioned above regarding setting fixed heights on text elements, absolute positioning can really bite you in the butt for pretty much the same reasons.

There's an overuse of id's here.  Yes, they are the fastest selector, but its efficiency is greatly exaggerated compared to class or element selectors.  Even descendant selectors are not as slow as many people make them out to be.

What *really* makes `#home` and `#aboutme` different?  Their positioning (which shouldn't be used anyway) and their background color?  When you have a lot of shared styles, they should be shifted to a common selector:

```
article {
    /* common styles */
}

#foo {
    background: blue;
}

#bar {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Be aware that using a custom font-face for the majority of your copy text is *not* a good idea from the user's perspective:  https://superuser.com/questions/547743/why-dont-websites-immediately-display-their-text-these-days

Comment: Thanks for all the tips cimmanon. So about the absolute positioning. I tried all the others and ended up with a white line on the left and right side of my screen. Only way to resolve it was to use absolute positioning. Any suggestions on how to do this otherwise?

Comment: Can you provide a [demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs) of the problem?

Comment: weird. in the cssdeck it doesn't give me the same issue. i did take a screenshot and you can see on my right monitor how the #home section which i took absolute positioning off of is indented slightly on the right and left compared to the #aboutme   http://imgur.com/G2XIuiw

Comment: i also have a question regarding custom font-faces...i skimmed that article you linked and see they are talking mostly about web fonts. Can i keep the font stored in some way that it is easily accessible by the site for users who do not have the font on their own computer?

Comment: The only way you can realistically expect a user to view a custom font that's not installed on their system is with `@font-face`.  It doesn't *have* to be hosted by Google, you can host it wherever you want provided you have the licensing to do so (the end result for the user will be the same).

Comment: Cssdeck uses a reset by default, which can cause different results (there is an option to turn it off).

Comment: A reset is exactly what I needed...used the one found here...http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to declare both a `html` and a `head` element twice:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>stan's page</title>
        ...
```

Here's how it should look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>stan's page</title>
        ...
```

Note that it's no longer required (but still allowed) to quote attributes in HTML5, unless they would otherwise be ambiguous (for instance, if they contain spaces).

You're also using a lot of `div`s. Since you're using a HTML5 doctype, you could change e.g.

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li id="home_link"><a href="#home">home</a></li><li id="about_link"><a href="#aboutme">about</a></li><li id="work_link"><a href="#work">work</a></li><li id="contact_link"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

to something like

```
<header>
    <nav>        
        <ul>
            <li id=home_link><a href=#home>home</a></li>
            <li id=about_link><a href=#aboutme>about</a></li>
            <li id=work_link><a href=#work>work</a></li>
            <li id=contact_link><a href=#contact>contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>        
</header>
```

Technically the closing `</li>` tag is no longer required, but some people (myself included) prefer to keep it.

Some of your other `div`s would probably be better of as `section` or maybe `article` elements; when to use each of those is often a judgement call as to whether a block can stand on its own or not.

[New Semantic Elements in HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html#new-elements) From [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info) has a good summary of the new elements available to you, and when to use them.

Comment: I disagree on the suggestion of the section element.  If the content is able to stand on its own, then an article tag is more appropriate.  It's also not invalid to use quotes around attributes and they *are* required if the attribute value has a space in it.

Comment: @cimmanon on attributes: I thought I was clear that quotes are "no longer required" rather than prohibited. I'll clarify my "ambiguous" comment to mention spaces.

Comment: Quotes were not required in HTML4 (unless there were spaces involved), either, but I consider it good practice to always include them, just like I consider it good practice to always provide a closing tag for every element even when it is optional.

Comment: @cimmanon but they *were* required (and a lot of people made a lot of fuss about it) in XHTML, and as a result many people erroneously believe they still are. Proponents of HTML5 are often just as opinionated about them being pointless fluff; it's really just a preference thing at this point (as with optional closing tags, as you point out).

Comment: What was required in XHTML is irrelevant:  HTML4 is the predecessor of HTML5.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9788/discussion-between-zero-piraeus-and-cimmanon)